# vue-chartjs horizontal bar chart

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I am using [Vue-chartjs](https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#creating-your-first-chart.) to create a bar graph in Vue 3:

The bars are vertical. How do I make them horizontal?

```html
<template>
  <Bar
    id="my-chart-id"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :data="chartData"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March' ],
        datasets: [ { data: [40, 20, 12] } ]
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `indexAxis` property.

```
<template>
  <Bar
    id="my-chart-id"
    :options="chartOptions"
    :data="chartData"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale)

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: [ 'January', 'February', 'March' ],
        datasets: [ { data: [40, 20, 12] } ]
      },
      chartOptions: {
        responsive: true,
        indexAxis: 'y'
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

When using a library, you can check their [documentation](https://vue-chartjs.org/api/) to find out more.

Then you would have found the props table;

[image]

which says:

> "options: The options object that is passed into the Chart.js chart".

You know that vue-chartjs is a Vue wrapper library for the Chart.js library. Therefore, you go to [their documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/). Then you go to the Chart Types part and find your chart type ([Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html)). If you scroll down a bit you find the options for Bar Charts. The obvious one that stands out to me is the indexAxis - and in fact - it works.

Demo: [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-star-wjrk52?file=/src/App.vue)